# Looking to write a 4-way temperature converter objective-c console program

Tags: objective-c

As some of you may have seen me experimenting with a program converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius and visa versa in Objective-C based off of console input and output.  I'm just doing this to better learn the language and I think its a good way to demonstrate some of the things I've been exposed to.

So, anyway, I am looking to incorporate both the Kelvin and Rankine scales into my program, a good suggestion I'd like to take up on proposed by dreamlax.

Now, up until this point, my program has functioned relatively well for converting between Fahrenheit and Celsius, but if I need to convert between these 4 different scales, I'm going to have to work at it a different way in my opinion.

First off, I need to provide the end-user with the choice of their starting temperature, the temperature they want to convert from.

In order to do this, I need to prompt them with an NSLog or printf statement instructing them to do this.

Now, I would rather have them type out Fahrenheit, Celsius, Kelvin or Rankine, based upon which ever one they would like, rather than 0-3.  Now, I don't think the scanf is capable, but if I'm wrong, I'd like to know if it either has this functionality, or this is another method I can take advantage of to add this to my program.

Next, I'm kind of lost.  I obviously would need to instruct them to pick their target temperature, in other words, the temperature they want to convert to.

I need some help on a recommendation on how to organize this in my program.. Should I use only 1 class?  Also, I guess I could set it up this way:

```
string baseTemp
string targetTemp

NSLog(@"Please type Fahrenheit, Celsius, Kelvin or Rankine to select your base temperature");
scanf or some other method here("string format specifier here" &baseTemp);
NSLog(@"Please type Fahrenheit, Celsius, Kelvin or Rankine to select your target temperature");
scanf or some other method here("string format specifier here" &targetTemp);
```

Now, I need a decision maker to decide if Fahrenheit == baseTemp and Celsius == targetTemp, then set up a certain formula accordingly.

This could get tedious, and I first off need that special decision maker, or just another simpler method.

Sorry for the probably quite awkward code, I'm trying to use what I've learned thus far here.

Any suggestions, tweaks, ideas and anything in between is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

**UPDATE UPDATE: UPDATE:**

The code for the class.h, class.m and main.m program files contain the final code, at least for this project, which dreamlax worked with me greatly to help us both achieve the goal I had.  Thanks again dreamlax!!

class.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface Temperature : NSObject

{
    double kelvin;
}

//Instance methods to convert argument to kevin
-(void) setFahrenheitValue: (double) f;
-(void) setCelsiusValue: (double) c;
-(void) setKelvinValue: (double) k;
-(void) setRankineValue: (double) r;

//Instance methods for extracting the kelvin value using any scale
-(double) fahrenheitValue;
-(double) celsiusValue;
-(double) kelvinValue;
-(double) rankineValue;

@end
```

---

class.m:

```
#import "class.h"

@implementation Temperature;

-(void) setFahrenheitValue: (double) f
{
    kelvin = ((f + 459.67)*(5.0/9.0));
}

-(void) setCelsiusValue: (double) c
{
    kelvin = (c + 273.15);
}

-(void) setKelvinValue: (double) k
{
    kelvin = k;
}

-(void) setRankineValue: (double) r
{
    kelvin = (r*(5.0/9.0));
}



-(double) fahrenheitValue
{
    return ((kelvin*(9.0/5.0)) - 459.67);
}

-(double) celsiusValue
{
    return (kelvin - 273.15);
}

-(double) kelvinValue
{
    return (kelvin);
}

-(double) rankineValue
{
    return (kelvin * (9.0/5.0));
}

@end
```

---

main.m:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "class.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result;
    int prompt;
    double sourceTemp;

    printf("Please choose a source temperature scale:\n[1] Fahrenheit\n[2] Celsius\n[3] Kelvin\n[4] Rankine\n\n");

    result = scanf("%i", &prompt);

    if (result != 1)
        printf("I couldn't understand your input, I need only one number!");

    else if (result == EOF)
        printf("I apologize, I encountered an error when trying to read your input.");

    else if (result == 1)
    {
    printf("\nNow, please enter the temperature you would like to convert:\n\n");

    scanf("%lf", &sourceTemp);

    Temperature *converter = [[Temperature alloc] init];

    switch (prompt) 
    {
        case 1:
            //end-user chooses Fahrenheit
            [converter setFahrenheitValue:sourceTemp];
            break;

        case 2:
            //end-user chooses Celsius
            [converter setCelsiusValue:sourceTemp];
            break;

        case 3:
            //end-user chooses Kelvin
            [converter setKelvinValue:sourceTemp];
            break;

        case 4:
            //end-user chooses Rankine
            [converter setRankineValue:sourceTemp];
            break;
    }

    printf("\nNow, please choose a target temperature scale:\n[1] Fahrenheit\n[2] Celsius\n[3] Kelvin\n[4] Rankine\n\n");

    scanf("%i", &prompt);

    switch (prompt) 
    {
        case 1:
            //end-user chooses Fahrenheit
            printf("%lf degrees Fahrenheit\n", [converter fahrenheitValue]);
            break;

        case 2:
            //end-user chooses Celsius
            printf("%lf degrees Celsius\n", [converter celsiusValue]);
            break;

        case 3:
            //end-user chooses Kelvin
            printf("%lf degrees Kelvin\n", [converter kelvinValue]);
            break;

        case 4:
            //end-user chooses Rankine
            printf("%lf degrees Rankine\n", [converter rankineValue]);
            break;
    }

    }

}
```

---

Just an idea I'm trying to implement is to get the final prompt which displays the converted temperature to display like this:

Suppose the end-user selected Fahrenheit as his/her source temperature, wishing to convert 212 degrees into his/her target temperature scale of Celsius.  The conversions should equal 100 degrees Celsius obviously, but I think the program would be better of displaying the result like this:

**212** degrees **Fahrenheit** is **100** degrees Celsius.

Now, I've made the values that need to be replaced by variables in bold.  I have the 212 and 100 values solved easily, because 100 has been there in the first place, and 212 can easily be remedied by replacing it with the string formatter of the sourceTemp variable.

Now, the Fahrenheit string is a bit different.

I have tried to establish something new in our original switch like so:

```
switch (prompt) 
{
    case 1:
        //end-user chooses Fahrenheit
        [converter setFahrenheitValue:sourceTemp];
        sourceTempText = 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        //end-user chooses Celsius
        [converter setCelsiusValue:sourceTemp];
        sourceTempText = 2;
        break;

    case 3:
        //end-user chooses Kelvin
        [converter setKelvinValue:sourceTemp];
        sourceTempText = 3;
        break;

    case 4:
        //end-user chooses Rankine
        [converter setRankineValue:sourceTemp];
        sourceTempText = 4;
        break;
}
```

OK, so I have added to each different case, setting a new variable named sourceTempText to either 1-4, the same value that the end-user chose to pick his/her source temperature.

Now, here is how I tried to display the final prompt to the end-user with the final switch:

```
switch (prompt2) 
{
    case 1:
        //end-user chooses Fahrenheit
        printf("%lf degrees sourceTempText is %lf degrees Fahrenheit\n", sourceTemp, [converter fahrenheitValue]);
        break;

    case 2:
        //end-user chooses Celsius
        printf("%lf degrees sourceTempText is %lf degrees Celsius\n", sourceTemp, [converter celsiusValue]);
        break;

    case 3:
        //end-user chooses Kelvin
        printf("%lf degrees sourceTempText is %lf degrees Kelvin\n", sourceTemp, [converter kelvinValue]);
        break;

    case 4:
        //end-user chooses Rankine
        printf("%lf degrees sourceTempText is %lf degrees Rankine\n", sourceTemp, [converter rankineValue]);
        break;
}
```

I am not sure now, if I can insert sourceTempText into the string like I have here, instead, maybe I have to use a string formatter, but I'm not sure.  It should be an easy fix, I just wanted to throw it out here! :)

Hopefully the next project will be... GUI GUI GUI! xD

Comment: Ahh, those errors are because you have forgotten to declare/define the `Temperature` class. Don't forget to include the `@interface Temperature` and `@implementation Temperature` parts!

Comment: Thanks! Man, I thought I imported those, anyway, for some reason, when I use #import to import my @implementation stored in my class.m, it gives me an exit error.  But when I, conversely, use #import to import the @interface section stored in my class.h file, everything works fine.  Isn't that kind of odd, because my class.m file is the one that uses #import to import the class.h file?

Comment: You are getting "main.m:50: warning: 'Temperature' may not respond to '-CelsiusValue'" because if you look in your .h file you will see the method you are trying to call is `-(double) celsiusValue;`, when you make the call in your code you are capitalizing the method.
Also, you never `#import` a .m file, the .h file is the one that tells the compiler what methods, etc exist in the class.

Comment: Also, don't forget, like in your previous question, you should check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that the user has entered something valid.

Comment: I actually didn't understand that part of your code before, that is why I did not implement it. Sorry, but do you think you could re-explain it a little?  Also, thanks for that fix again, man my lame naming skills xD, and also, I need to take a look at the conversion formulas because the temperatures don't appear to be calculating correctly.

Comment: @BOSS: Sorry if the formulas are incorrect, they are off the top of my head just like the code, haha! I will edit my answer to explain the `scanf` issue.

Comment: @BOSS: You're so close! [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin) contains the formulas required for converting to and from Kelvin, so you should be able to spot what's up.

Comment: I know, I know.. :)  Well, I did notice one of the Fahrenheit formulas was off, but other than that, I cannot find anything wrong, and for some reason, that didn't appear to fix the program's fahrenheit conversions anyway.  Also, maybe it's not with the formula definitions, but rather, in the program's main function, or even in its interface where the problem lies.

Comment: You can use `NSLog` to make sure that the numbers have been interpreted properly by `scanf`. `NSLog(@"%lf", sourceTemp);` and so on. How far off are each of the conversions? Miles off or only marginally off?

Comment: I just updated, check out the value comparisons.  OK, about NSLog I think.

Comment: @BOSS: OK, I've found the problem. It is because of the division `(9/5)`. 9 and 5 are both integers, so the result is also an integer, therefore this will always equal 1 (similarly, the divion of `(5/9)` is always going to equal 0). You should change each `(9/5)` to `(9.0/5.0)` and each `(5/9)` to `(5.0/9.0)`. That should fix it! :)

Comment: Awww, such a simple mistake, I've already covered this before too!  Oh well, thanks for spotting that, and everything is working stellar now.  Thank you SOOO SO much for the help, this has really helped me learn some more objc-c!

Comment: @BOSS: Not a problem! Glad to help. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 4):

With regards to your class, one approach that I briefly touched on in your previous question could be:

1. It should store the value using only one temperature scale. Keep in mind that Rankine is to Fahrenheit what Kelvin is to Celsius. What I mean is that Rankine is simply Fahrenheit but with a different offset, and Kelvin is simply Celsius but with a different offset (Rankine and Kelvin both consider 0° to be [*absolute zero*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Zero)). Scientifically, Kelvin would be a good choice of base scale since it is the [international standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit) for temperature measurements (USA, Burma and Liberia are the only countries that have not adopted the SI system). There are some pros and cons to using only one temperature scale:

   - There will be a loss of precision because you are converting twice (once to convert the source scale to kelvin, and then another conversion to convert to the user's desired scale)
   - However, the implementation of your class will be simpler because there is only one variable.
2. You only need one instance of your Converter class. When you read input from the command line, you tell the Converter class instance the measurement as well as the scale that the user chose. For example, your Converter interface could adopt the following methods:

   ```
   @interface Temperature : NSObject
   {
       double kelvin;
   }
   - (void) setCelsiusValue:(double) c; // kelvin = (c + 273.15)
   - (void) setKelvinValue:(double) k; // kelvin = k
   - (void) setFahrenheitValue:(double) f; // kelvin = (f + 459.67) × 5⁄9
   - (void) setRankineValue:(double) r; // kelvin = (f × 5/9)
   @end
   ```

   All of these methods should convert the argument into the Kelvin scale.
3. Your class should also implement ways to extract the value using any scale. It could adopt the following methods for that purpose:

   ```
   @interface Temperature : NSObject
   {
       double kelvin;
   }
   // include methods from above
   - (double) celsiusValue; // return kelvin - 273.15
   - (double) kelvinValue; // return kelvin
   - (double) fahrenheitValue; // return kelvin × 9⁄5 − 459.67
   - (double) rankineValue; // return kelvin × 9/5
   @end
   ```

   Each of these methods should convert the Kelvin value into the relevant scale using the appropriate formula.

With regards to user interaction, typically `NSLog` is used only for logging information about your application during runtime (for example, to inspect what an object's value is or to determine the point of execution in your application). For asking questions it is usually more mainstream to use `printf`.

You could print out a menu like this:

```
Please choose a source temperature scale:
[1] Celsius
[2] Kelvin
[3] Fahrenheit
[4] Rankine
```

Then print out another menu for the target temperature scale, and then ask the user for the source temperature measurement. Generally you should not ask a user to type out a full word because it is easier to mistype than a simple number. There's also a special programming construct called a `switch`. It has some caveats but works nicely with multi-choice question/answers. Once you have read the user's input using `scanf`, you can do this:

```
int prompt;
double sourceTemp;
// use scanf to read values into prompt and sourceTemp variables

Temperature *converter = [[Temperature alloc] init];
switch(prompt)
{
    case 1: // the user chose celsius
        [converter setCelsiusValue:sourceTemp];
        break; // if you don't break, it will execute all other cases

    case 2: // user chose kelvin
        [converter setKelvinValue:sourceTemp];
        break;

    case 3:
        [converter setFahrenheitValue:sourceTemp];
        break;

    case 4:
        [converter setRankineValue:sourceTemp];
        break;
}

// prompt the user again here to determine the target temperature scale
// use the same menu again and read the user's input into the prompt variable

case (prompt)
{
    case 1: // user wants to convert to celsius
         printf("%f degrees C\n", [converter celsiusValue]);
         break;

    case 2: // user wants kelvin
         printf("%f degrees K\n", [converter kelvinValue]);
         break;

    case 3:
         printf("%f degrees F\n", [converter fahrenheitValue]);
         break;

    case 4:
         printf("%f degrees R\n", [converter rankineValue]);
         break;
}
```

---

With regards to `scanf`, it does two things. Firstly, it scans input into the provided variables, and secondly it returns the number of items successfully scanned. For example:

```
int result;
int first;
int second;

printf("Please type two numbers: ");
result = scanf("%d %d", &first, &second);
```

If `scanf` successfully read two numbers, then `result` should equal 2. If it is equal to 2, then you can be certain that `first` and `second` contain good data, you can be certain that `scanf` has scanned the input successfully. Similarly, if you only ask `scanf` to read one number, then if `result` is equal to 1 then it successfully read that one number.

If `result` is 1, then it means that it only scanned one number, and then encountered a problem. For example, if the user has typed “100 abc”, `scanf` will only be able to read one number, but we've asked for two. In this case, it will return 1 to tell us that it has only scanned one integer.

If `result` is 0, then it means that `scanf` was unable to scan *anything* that matches what we asked for (if the user entered “abc abc” for example).

Lastly, `result` will be `EOF` (end-of-file) if there was no data to read.

So, it is important to check the return value of `scanf` calls to make sure that the user has entered something valid. If the result is 0, you know the user has entered something invalid, and if the result is `EOF` then there was a problem reading any data at all. So, we could have this setup:

```
int result;
int first;
int second;

printf("Please type two numbers: ");
result = scanf("%d %d", &first, &second);

if (result == 0)
    printf("I couldn't understand what you gave me, I need numbers!\n");
else if (result == 1)
    printf("I was only able to read one number!\n");
else if (result == EOF)
    printf("Whoops, there was some problem trying to read your input\n");
else if (result == 2) // scanf was able to read two numbers
    printf("Great! The sum of those two numbers is: %d\n", first + second);
```

Comment: Wow wow wow, thank you SO MUCH!!! :)

I have been working to implement your structure, and I am really lovin' your fix.  Just a question, what is the double sourceTemp variable you declared in the main function?  What is that doing exactly?  Is that to store the data that the end-user inputs as their actual base temperature, say 42 degrees for example?  Thank you SO much once again, this is helping out so much!

Comment: That's right, `sourceTemp` is the temperature that the user has provided. You first ask the user what the temperature scale is, read that into `prompt`, and then ask what the temperature value is, and read that into `sourceTemp` (use the "%f" format specifier for the `scanf` call to allow the user to provide values like 43.23)

Comment: Great!  Now, for some reason, when I'm proceeding along, working on the main.m code, trying to base it off of your suggestions, when I build and run and try and test the following code in my update, I get 5 errors..  I'm wondering if it's possible that I should just complete the program first, and then look back and build and run.

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting? If they are syntax errors they can be easily fixed (I typed this whole thing without compiling or testing, so be careful!).

Comment: Ahaha, I'm actually typing most of them out so I can get a feel for them, so I may be creating my own syntax error :p, let me list the errors in an update..

Comment: Lols, I missed the semicolon after declaring sourceTemp xD

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know scanf actually had this functionality, which actually makes it pretty useful for what we're trying to do here, and thanks so much for explaining it like that!